# Need to keep each binlog files to 24 hrs

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

We have a requirement werein we need to keep each binlog files(like mysql-bin-changelog.025249, mysql-bin-changelog.025250, mysql-bin-changelog.025251....) of MYSQL RDS to minimum 24 hrs.

However, i see that binlog files are getting purged/deleted after 10-12 mins.

Below is the current setup in my RDS parameter group-:
1.binlog retention hours is set to 24 hrs.
2.max_binlog_size is set to 134217728
3.binlog_expire_logs_seconds is set to 2592000.

Also, my MYSQL RDS database is heavily used and has 400+ tables.

Please let me know which parameter i need to change, so that each bin log should be retained for 24 hrs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the AWS RDS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_set_configuration.html), you call a stored procedure to set the binary log retention

```
call mysql.rds_set_configuration('binlog retention hours', 24);
```

Here's some relevent information from the docs

> The binlog retention hours parameter is used to specify the number of
> hours to retain binary log files. Amazon RDS normally purges a binary
> log as soon as possible, but the binary log might still be required
> for replication with a MySQL database external to Amazon RDS. The
> default value of binlog retention hours is NULL.
>
> The binlog retention hours parameter is used to specify the number of
> hours to retain binary log files. Amazon RDS normally purges a binary
> log as soon as possible, but the binary log might still be required
> for replication with a MySQL database external to Amazon RDS. The
> default value of binlog retention hours is NULL.
>
> ...
>
> For MySQL DB instances, the maximum binlog retention hours value is
> 168 (7 days).
>
> After you set the retention period, monitor storage usage for the DB
> instance to make sure that the retained binary logs don't take up too
> much storage.